# php-fpm being run by 2 users causing permission issues

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, nginx

my `ps aux | grep php-fpm` output

```
root     22583  0.0  0.3 447796 26580 ?        Ss   15:00   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/7.3/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
www-data 22605  0.0  0.7 1420740 58344 ?       S    15:00   0:01 php-fpm: pool www
www-data 22608  0.0  0.4 457224 40184 ?        S    15:00   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
ubuntu   23865  0.0  0.0  15184  1044 pts/1    S+   17:08   0:00 grep --color=auto php-fpm
```

as you can see in the last line `php-fpm` is ran by `ubuntu` instead of `www-data` (I use nginx + php, where nginx user is `www-data` **Where I assume my problem lies**). So in my application (Laravel based) the log files are being created on behalf of the `ubuntu` user. When the application is running its throwing permission denied error. Because it can't read the log files.

When I chown the log files to `www-data` it works fine. But every new log file is owned by the `ubuntu` user, and then I will have to `chown` them every day :(. How can I change the user of the `php-fpm` essentially to fix the permission issues?

**Edit:** also I have added the `ubuntu` user to `www-data` group but still `ubuntu` can't edit any files owned by `www-data`

Comment: In symfony i use setfacl https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/setup/file_permissions.html#using-acl-on-a-system-that-supports-setfacl-linux-bsd, can help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use setfacl

```
HTTPDUSER=$(ps axo user,comm | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1)
sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:$(whoami):rwX /log/folder/laravel/project
sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:$(whoami):rwX /log/folder/laravel/project
```

See symfony docs: https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/setup/file_permissions.html#using-acl-on-a-system-that-supports-setfacl-linux-bsd

Comment: I tried. But mostly when a new log file is getting created its owned by ubuntu.

Comment: Yes @Shobi, but also www-data can write them. Do you don't want ubuntu owned files? Only www-data?

Comment: Just restarted server. And seems like your answer fixed the issue for now,  thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, your web server user is the one that should be creating the log file (www-data). Le log file should be writable by the same user the web server is running as.

I would suggest the permissions are set as follow :

`chmod -R 755 storage/`

After installing Laravel, you may need to configure some permissions. Directories within the storage and the bootstrap/cache directories should be writable by your web server or Laravel will not run.

You can also take a look at the permissions documentation for Laravel 5.8 local driver :
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#the-local-driver

You also have the possibility to change php-fpm and nginx user and group in their respective configuration files.